# How to get multiple entries of same entity from html form in java object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my AcademicQualification class where i am trying to map the multiple 
entries from html form.

```
@Entity
public class AcademicQualification {
private String university;
private String faculty;
private String percentage;
private Date passed_year;
@Id
private int id;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name="student_id",nullable = false,insertable = true )
private EnquiryForm enquiryform;
```

This is my Parent entity which has relation with academicqualification

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int Student_id;
private  int Staff_id;

public List<AcademicQualification> getAcademicQualifications() {
    return academicQualifications;
}

public void setAcademicQualifications(List<AcademicQualification> 
academicQualifications) {
    this.academicQualifications = academicQualifications;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "enquiryform",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval 
 = true)

@JsonManagedReference

private List<AcademicQualification> academicQualifications;
```

This is how i get single academic info but i want like three academic info from html form in single request . SO how can i map these multiple entries into object or what is the coreect way

```
 @PostMapping("/academic")
public boolean relationtry(@RequestBody enquirydto edto) {
EnquiryForm eq = new EnquiryForm();
AcademicQualification ac= new AcademicQualification();
eq.setStudent_mname(edto.getStudent_mname());
eq.setStudent_lname(edto.getStudent_lname());
............
..........
EnquiryForm eq = new EnquiryForm();
AcademicQualification ac= new AcademicQualification();
............
................
ac.setFaculty(edto.getFaculty());
ac.setPassed_year(edto.getPassed_year());
ac.setPercentage(edto.getPercentage());
ac.setUniversity(edto.getUniversity());
List<AcademicQualification> listacademic = new ArrayList<>();
listacademic.add(ac);
ac.setEnquiryform(eq);
eq.setAcademicQualifications(listacademic);
enquiryRepository.save(eq);
```

This is the sample Json

```
{
"date_of_issue": "2019-01-02",
"student_fname": "fdfd",
"student_mname": "dfdf",
"student_lname": "fdf",
"father_name": "fd",
"mother_name": "dfd",
"student_address": "dfd",
"student_contact": "df",
"guardian_name": "df",
"preferred_country": "fd",
"student_dob": "2019-01-02",
"student_email": "fd@gmail.com",
"academicQualifications": [
    {
        "university": "uni",
        "faculty": "fa",
        "percentage": "per",
        "passed_year": "2019-01-08",
        "id": 21
    },
    {
        "university": "SA",
        "faculty": "SA",
        "percentage": "PER",
        "passed_year": "2019-01-08",
        "id": 22
    },
    {
        "university": "DSDS",
        "faculty": "SAD",
        "percentage": "PER",
        "passed_year": "2019-01-02",
        "id": 23
    }
],
"staff_id": 1,
"student_id": 34
```

}

Issue i am having is I can take 1 set of data from AcademicQualification as a java object but how can i get all three set of AcademicQualifications

Comment: which spring-boot starter project are you using? `Spring-REST` or `Spring MVC`?

Comment: i am using spring rest

Comment: You can pass an array of JSON objects in `POST` body, Spring will serialize it for you. provided JSON is well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can automatically serialize the JSON Objects to `Collection`
For eg. have a look at below `json`

```
[
    {
        "university":"Stanford",
        "faculty":"Andy",
        "percentage":"98"
    },
    {
        "university":"MIT",
        "faculty":"Mark",
        "percentage":"99"
    }
]
```

If your json model is as above, it can be serialized as below.

```
@PostMapping(value = "consumeList", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String consumeList(@RequestBody List<AcademicQualification> academicQualifications) throws IOException {
    System.out.println ("Voila!");
    return "Done";
}
```

For the demo purpose, I am returning a plain text.

Comment: I have added my sample json .. I have a method that serialize json shown above with Enquiry class as parent that has onetomany relation with AcademicQualification. I can get one set of AcademicQualification as object  but my actual problem is how can i get all three set of data in AcademicQualification. I have added my method that serializes json in question as well . 
Thanks for your response